# How to Add Current_User to Nested Attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

- name
- metric
- date_value
- result_value

None of the above attributes are showing when I load the index page.

I know its because of this line: **<% if averaged.user == current_user %>**

More specifically it's because of the nested attributes of date_value and result_value (because if I take out those nested attributes the name & metric will show)

What do I need to add to the controller to allow the nested attributes to show on the index page, and in effect all the attributes?

Thanks in advance for your service!

```html
<div id="values" class="panel panel-default">
  
  <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b>AVERAGE</b></h4></div>

  <!-- Table -->
<table>
  <% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
    <% if averaged.user == current_user %>
        <th class="value">
          <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(averaged) do %>
          <%= averaged.name %>
          <% end %>
          (<%= averaged.metric %>)
        </th>
      <tbody class="value"> 
          <td><%= averaged.date_value.strftime("%m-%Y") %></td>
          <td><%= averaged.result_value %></td>
      </tbody>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
</div>
```

**controller**

```html
class QuantifiedsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quantified, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
   @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
   @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
   @averaged_quantifieds = Result.all.order("date_value")
   @instance_quantifieds = Result.all.order("date_value")
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build
    @quantified = Quantified.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build(quantified_params)
    if @quantified.save
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Quantified was successfully created'
    else
      render action: 'new'
  end
end

  def update
    if @quantified.update(quantified_params)
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @quantified.destroy
    redirect_to quantifieds_url
  end

  private
    def set_quantified
      @quantified = Quantified.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to quantifieds_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @quantified.nil?
    end

    def quantified_params
      params.require(:quantified).permit(:categories, :name, :metric, :result, :date, results_attributes: [:id, :result_value, :date_value, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

**quantified.rb**

```html
class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'averaged') }
  scope :instance,  -> { where(categories: 'instance') }
  has_many :results
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

 CATEGORIES = ['averaged', 'instance']

end
```

Please let me know if you need any more code or comments to help bring this question to a resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hopefully guide you in the right direction

This is odd to me

```
  def index
   @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged 
   @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
   @averaged_quantifieds = Result.all.order("date_value")
   @instance_quantifieds = Result.all.order("date_value")
  end
```

You define both of these twice and essentially overwrite each other?

If your attributes aren't showing, it doesn't have anything to do with the nesting, it has to do with the logic. So in other words, this logic

```
if averaged.user == current_user
```

is not evaluating to true, so check what each object is actually holding. You can do this in a dirty way by just inspecting it in the view

e.g. put `<%= averaged.user.inspect` %> and `<%= current_user.inspect %>`

Once you know what objects it's holding, go backwards in your code to how you altered them to this state. I suspect it'll go back to the controller where you have some issues.